# How to find the NetBiosName of a domain using the ExecuteSearch API

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I am working on a C++ project and have to find NetBiosName of a domain using the ExecuteSearch windows API. I am using the below piece of code

```
  ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN col;
     LPWSTR            attrName = NULL; 
     CoInitialize(NULL);    
     LPWSTR pszAttr[] = { L"ADsPath", L"Name" };
     ADS_SEARCHPREF_INFO SearchPrefs;
     SearchPrefs.dwSearchPref = ADS_SEARCHPREF_SEARCH_SCOPE;
     SearchPrefs.vValue.dwType = ADSTYPE_INTEGER;
     SearchPrefs.vValue.Integer = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE;
     DWORD             dwNumPrefs = 1;
     hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://dc=Bangalore,dc=local",
        NULL,
        NULL,
    
        /* Use Secure Authentication */
        ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
        IID_IDirectorySearch,
        (void **)&pContainerToSearch);  
    
    
    
    hr = pContainerToSearch->SetSearchPreference(searchPrefs, dwNumPrefs);
    hr = pContainerToSearch->ExecuteSearch(L"(objectCategory=domain)",
    filter,
    (DWORD)dwCount,
    &hSearch);
```

The attributes I am giving for the search are "ADsPath" and  "Name" as seen above, The "Name" is returning me the first part of the domain, I am assuming this is the NetBiosName. Please let me know if my assumption is right.

Comment: Ignoring that `pszAttr` has the wrong type, you aren't using it anywhere. Can we see the [mcve] your question promised to provide?

Comment: you need use `LsaQueryInformationPolicy` with `PolicyDnsDomainInformation`

Comment: Do you want to get the name of local or remote server? What format of the name do you expect?